# Laravel 5.2 with Select2 v 3.5.1 ajax method POST, token mismatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I am trying to use Select2 using type: POST and try to pass the token through headers just like ajax request. But I got TokenMismatchException.
But I've already tried use Select2 using GET and it works fine.
Is it possible to use Select2 with type POST or just GET?
Here is my code

```
var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
$(".eta").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for source",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
        url: '{{route("part", "source")}}',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        },
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, // search term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            console.log(data);
            dataSourceParts = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                dataSourceParts.push({
                    id: val.id,
                    text: val.name+'-'+val.code
                });
            });
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter the remote JSON data
            return { results: dataSourceParts };
        },
        cache: true
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me:

```
headers: {
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{!! csrf_token() !!}'
},
```

Simply add quotes. And generate token with raw blade params to not to be escaped it with {!! !!}.